# Stacked bordered boxes with joints?

Tags: html, css, menu, border

I don't know a better way to describe it, but what I'm trying to recreate is a border that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KojGF.jpg), so borders all around and in between all the `nav-link` elements, with square outside corners and rounded inside corners (that make them look a bit like joints where two boxes connect). The closest I've gotten is what you can see in the snippet below.

It's probably not done with borders at all, but then how? It's also not a png image on top of the links or something like that, because it is responsive. I'm a beginner with CSS, so that's all the options I can think of myself.

```css
.container-fluid {
    background-color: #105565;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
   
.navbar-nav {
    border: solid 2px white;
    margin: 10px;
}
    
#navinc .nav-link {
    border: solid 2px white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #105565;
    font-family: 'roboto';
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,300italic,400,700|Julius+Sans+One|Roboto+Condensed:300,400" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
<body>
   <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="navbar-nav" id="navinc">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link home" aria-current="page" href="#carousel">HOME</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link over" aria-current="page" href="#">OVER</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link merken" aria-current="page" href="#">MERKEN</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link team" aria-current="page" href="#">TEAM</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link contact" aria-current="page" href="#">CONTACT</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding a white background color and border-radius to the `navbar-nav`.

```css
.container-fluid {
    background-color: #105565;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
   
.navbar-nav {
    border: solid 2px white;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
    
#navinc .nav-link {
    border: solid 1px white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #105565;
    font-family: 'roboto';
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,300italic,400,700|Julius+Sans+One|Roboto+Condensed:300,400" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
<body>
   <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="navbar-nav" id="navinc">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link home" aria-current="page" href="#carousel">HOME</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link over" aria-current="page" href="#">OVER</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link merken" aria-current="page" href="#">MERKEN</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link team" aria-current="page" href="#">TEAM</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link contact" aria-current="page" href="#">CONTACT</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: So simple! Thanks a lot!